# How to spot folder of some application on Android (Galaxy Note 5)?

Tags: backup

I intend to reset my phone to get rid of bad applications. I will reinstall all applications wanted, but there is the notes application I use that I want to get the data of (no option to back up notes)... how do I get the data?

the application is called [Notes by programmer "Office"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edi.masaki.mymemoapp)

Comment: Please always include the Play Store link to the app you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The application, Notes by Microsoft, stores your entries on OneDrive, they are not stored locally on your mobile device. This also means that your notes are always backed up.

If you remove the Notes application from your mobile device, you will have to log back into it when after you reinstall.

Comment: I don't think it's related to MS? I'm talking about an Android app, called Notes, (by "Office" ... an android developer)

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edi.masaki.mymemoapp

Comment: I am trying to spot the folder of the App.. I think it's the only way to get it's data (to move it to another device)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access the following folder `/data/data/com.edi.masaki.mymemoapp`, open it. Then do the following:

1. Open the databases folder. Copy the following files:

```
myapp.db
myapp.db-journal
```

The first files contains the memos. You can open it and view the memos with apps that are capable to open sqlite database (search Play Store for sqlite apps, I use SQLPrime).

2. After installing/reinstalling, open then close Notes (close it also from the Recent apps). Go to `/data/data/com.edi.masaki.mymemoapp/databases`, delete the files found there, and paste the files from step 1.
3. Open Notes, you will find your files.

Comment: Access to `/data/data´ is limited to rooted devices. The question doe snot say anything about rooting.

Comment: @Robert I did not write anything about rooting, only how to access the app's data.

Comment: Hence your information if worthless unless the device is rooted.

Comment: @Robert Maybe, maybe not

Comment: I can access Android > data > where there are lots of apps folders; but I can't find "com.edi.masaki.mymemoapp"

Comment: there is folder (somewhere, I moved it).. it's called inappad. it has shared3.0.db, and shared3.0.db-journal... journal doesn't open, .db opens with only two cells, which isn't even a text (some random numbers)

Comment: @w4j3d The folder is /data/data/com.edi.masaki.mymemoapp. Then under /data/data/com.edi.masaki.mymemoapp/databases. you will find the files I wrote about.